# react-chartjs-2: how to fix stepSize on y axis without knowing max range

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-chartjs-2

I'm trying to fix stepSize to 1 on y axis in my Line chart using:

```
const options = {
    scales: {
      y:
        {
          min: 0,
          stepSize: 1,
        },
      x:
        {
          
        },
    },
  };
```

it is starting from zero, but at intervals of 5 units. I know we can set it by specifying min AND max but I'm getting the graph data dynamically and can't be sure about max.

Is there any other keyword for stepSize?